# Load Individual Add-in with MEF

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to load an individual add-in using MEF. My scenario is as follows: when my application starts, it will search for a set of add-ins and load them into my app.

After this start-up phase, I would like the user to be able to load an add-in of their choosing. This is the bit I'm really struggling with.

My initial loading code is as follows:

```
    var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer();

    var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(@"C:\MyPath\Experiment.dll");

    .. catalogs for other addins..
    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(assemblyCatalog);

    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);

    foreach (var addin in addins)
    {
        addin.OnLoad(this);
    }
```

I feel I should be able to add the new add-in to the catalog in the existing container, but I cannot find any way of adding it. The following does not work:

```
var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(filePath);
var catalog = this.compositionContainer.Catalog as AggregateCatalog;
catalog.Catalogs.Add(assemblyCatalog);
this.compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
```

How can I load the add-in that is in the dll at *filePath*. Furthermore, is there any way that I can call the .OnLoad method on that new add-in without calling it on the ones already loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're looking for is already implemented in the [Prism library](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). Specifically you should have a look at its [modularity documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) and demo.

Prism can manage your add-ins (modules in Prism terms) and allows you to load them immediately or on demand. When a module is loaded, its `Initialize` method (which is implemented by every module via the `IModule` interface) is called, so there won't be any redundant initialization calls.

I should also mention that Prism supports MEF out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Adi. That demo application is brilliant and absolutely the kind of functionality that I am looking for.